# How to measure interval time with python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, intervals

I have following formats of data

```
start = '10:00:00'
end = '12:05:00'
```

My interval time wanna show like simple 2 hours 5 minutes 0 second
in this case i've used datetime and timedelta

## code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = '10:00:00'
end = '12:05:00'
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
interval_time = datetime.strptime(end, FMT) - datetime.strptime(start, FMT)
print(interval_time)

if interval_time.days < 0:
    tdiff = timedelta(days=0,
                      seconds=interval_time.seconds, microseconds=interval_time.microseconds)
    print(tdiff)
```

This condition is false, Cause here is no day yet and here i wanna use hours instead of day.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

'

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? What is your expected behaviour or output, and how does the actual result differ from your expectations?

Comment: my last code was just a sample to understand my code

Comment: Where is `login` coming in to this? There's no `login` anywhere in your example code or your question. Can you try to clarify what the posted code is supposed to do, and how that differs from what it's actually doing?

Comment: actually i don't understand your words that where you have found login in my code. just there  were 2 variant name of start and end and from here i want to measure my interval time.

Comment: Your comment: "there has login hours = 0 will be instead of days=0"

Comment: oh in my comment that was mistake sorry for that i thought about my code. whatever i think my problem you can understand

Comment: my last condition if interval_time.total_seconds() < 0: here if i use interval_time.days() then it works fine for days. output look like 1 day 10:12:20 something like that